# R language | sodium | cyphr | How to save and transfer a KEY

Tags: r, encryption, rstudio

I'm working on encrypting a `csv.` file as a local user and decrypting the same file as a remote user, using `R` language with the help of `sodium` and `cyphr` packages. I came across this documentation which suffices the requirement (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/cyphr/versions/1.0.2/topics/key_sodium). However, I face a stumbling block in saving and transferring the key to the remote user.

Adapted example from the documentation *(limiting to a `string` instead of `csv.`)*:

```
### Encryption at local user
# Create a new key
key <- cyphr::key_sodium(sodium::keygen())
key
# With this key encrypt a string
secret <- saveRDS(cyphr::encrypt_string("my secret string", key)


# Decryption at remote user:
cyphr::decrypt_string(secret, key)
```

**How can I share the key to the remote user for decryption?** Although I did try to save the `key` to a `.rds` or `file` format and loaded it back to R, but the key is no more a `<cyphr_key: sodium>` object *(using `save` and `load` commands)*.

Below is the error while I try to decrypt as remote user:

```
Error: 'key' must be a cyphr_key
```

Any guidance on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for how to transmit a key to a remote user, see this [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/53631/how-to-securely-share-key-between-two-remote-devices) post.

The error comes from the fact that `saveRDS` does not return a value. And you have not saved anything to a file, that code line gives an error. The right way of encrypting *and* saving to a file would be

```
key <- cyphr::key_sodium(sodium::keygen())

saveRDS(cyphr::encrypt_string("my secret string", key),
                  file = "test.rds")

secret <- readRDS("test.rds")
secret
# [1] 75 fc bb fd e3 07 66 3e 9b 72 ac ca c7 f5 3a ed 7c d7 e0 b0 ad 3e 53 ba
#[25] e7 dd 14 5e 64 0f 06 51 17 fe e1 f3 aa b9 27 7c 6e 8e 02 55 ae 68 0a 0f
#[49] 89 6c 17 b0 4f 83 3d ea

cyphr::decrypt_string(secret, key)
#[1] "my secret string"
```

As for the problem of saving the key to a file, it's a normal `saveRDS` call followed by a `readRDS` call.

See what is a key.

```
class(key)
#[1] "cyphr_key"

str(key)
#List of 4
# $ type   : chr "sodium"
# $ key    :function ()  
# $ encrypt:function (msg)  
# $ decrypt:function (msg)  
# - attr(*, "class")= chr "cyphr_key"
```

Now save it to file `"key.rds"`, remove the object `key` from the `.GlobalEnv` and read it from file.

```
saveRDS(key, "key.rds")
rm(key)
key <- readRDS("key.rds")
```

Did it work?

```
class(key)
#[1] "cyphr_key"

str(key)
#List of 4
# $ type   : chr "sodium"
# $ key    :function ()  
# $ encrypt:function (msg)  
# $ decrypt:function (msg)  
# - attr(*, "class")= chr "cyphr_key"
```

Apparently it did, check if it correctly decrypts the string.

```
cyphr::decrypt_string(secret, key)
#[1] "my secret string"
```

Final clean-up.

```
unlink("test.rds")
unlink("key.rds")
```

Comment: that did work perfectly fine. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Rui, Could you please look into a follow-up [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60561129/error-failed-to-decrypt-key-as-session-key-has-changed-shinyapps-io-r)? @RuiBarradas